# Haskell: Show all the elements that are "showable" on a Hlist

Tags: haskell, reflection, hlist

I have tried

```
map show . mapMaybe fromDynamic $ [toDyn "one", toDyn (\x -> x::Integer), toDyn 3, toDyn ()]
```

but it returned

```
["()"]
```

Comment: Do you _really_ need to store the data mixed up in a list like that?

Comment: You could use a record to store that data much more easily, for example, and you'd easily be able to use functions like show on the elements because the types are available at runtime. Having types fixed at runtime is an advantage, not a disadvantage, so you should do it whenever possible.

Comment: This problem was made up to illustrate my problem. The project I am working is here github.com/rbarreiro/farofias The next step in the project is to add functions, which are not instance of Data.Data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code does not do what you expect it to do. Long before the dynamic behaviour of `Data.Dynamic` kicks in, the Haskell type checker resolves the types. The type of the right part of the expression is

```
mapMaybe fromDynamic $ [toDyn "one", toDyn (\x -> x::Integer), toDyn 3, toDyn ()] :: Typeable b => [b]
```

and the type of the left part is

```
map show :: Show a => [a] -> [String]
```

so to combine these, the type variable `b` resp. `a` gets unified. If you were to compile this from a regular Haskell file, the compiler would give you a warning (`` The type variable `a' is ambigous ``). But in GHCi, the interpreter just defaults to `()`.

But this fixes the type of `fromDynamic` in the expression to `Dynamic -> Maybe ()`, effectively selecting all elements of type `()`.

If you force the compiler to use a different type there, e.g. by specifying a type signature, you see that `fromDynamic` selects a different type:

```
Prelude Data.Dynamic Data.Maybe> map (show :: Integer -> String) . mapMaybe fromDynamic $ [toDyn "one", toDyn (\x -> x::Integer), toDyn 3, toDyn ()]
["3"]
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to achieve what you want: Select all elements whose type support a show instance, as that information is not available to `fromDynamic`.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `fromDynamic` must go to a monomorphic type.  It is picking `()`, but with a type signature you could make it pick any other type.

To show it, you would need some function that tries all the possible types in turn.  Probably you do not want to store the data like this, but want to store it bundled up with some operations (such as show).

There are two ways you could bundle.  My favourite is to have all the functions pre-applied to the value (so for show, you just get a list of thunks of type `String`).

The other way is to also put the functions into a `Dynamic` (make sure they are the correct monomorphic type!) and then use `dynApply`.

Comment: nice idea:  "store it bundled up with some operations"